# Caps Lock as Control key does not (always) work as Control

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, gmail

For using Caps Lock as Control key, I chose (Ubuntu 13.04) `System Settings -> Keyboard -> Typing -> Layout Settings -> Options... -> Caps Lock key behavior -> Make Caps Lock an additional Control but keep the Caps_Lock keysym`. This works perfectly fine, I use Caps Lock as Control all the time. However, when sending an Email via GMail, the shortcut `Caps Lock + Return` does *not* send the email, although `Control` (the good old control key) `+ Return` does. Shouldn't `Caps Lock` be just another `Control` and thus work? Is the problem the `"but keep the Caps_Lock keysym"`?

Comment: Can you just test it? Turn that setting off and try` Ctrl key position` > `Caps Lock as Ctrl` and see if that works. (I suspect that you have correctly identified the problem.)

Comment: Ahh... I was always looking for s.th. like this, but I looked in the submenu `Caps Lock key behavior` instead of "one level above". Okay, I reset `Caps Lock key behavior` to `default` and `Ctrl key position` to `Caps Lock as Ctrl` as you suggested -- and it works!

Comment: Great! I've added this as an answer. (I'm not 100% sure what the `Make Caps Lock an additional Control but keep the Caps_Lock keysym` setting does. Does it allow the Caps Lock to be used as both a ctrl and caps lock? Presumably you are not interested in this function anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are correct that the `but keep the Caps_Lock keysym` is to blame. Turn that setting off and try `Ctrl key position` > `Caps Lock as Ctrl` and see if that works.